# C# Substring on a Windows Mobile Device throwing an 'out of valid range' error with valid range

Tags: c#, mobile, substring

My code:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Flash Disk/thing.ini"))
            {
                text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                int length = text.Length;  //3722
                int indexStart = text.IndexOf("DeviceName="); //3126
                int indexEnd = text.IndexOf("DeviceID="); //3145
                string deviceName = text.Substring(indexStart, indexEnd);
                Console.WriteLine(name);
            }
```

It is blowing up at the 
    string deviceName = text.Substring(indexStart, indexEnd);

I am getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException and it tells me 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.'  Nothing else.

I am lost here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your question, the total string Length is `4752`

```
int length = text.Length;  //4752
```

But [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) the second parameter number represents the number of characters you want to retrieve.

In your code, start as `indexStart(4176)` and retrieve  `indexEnd(4195)` that will over the string Length.

I think you need to use `indexEnd - indexStart` on the second parameter

```
int indexStart = text.IndexOf("DeviceName="); //4176
int indexEnd = text.IndexOf("DeviceID="); //4195
string deviceName = text.Substring(indexStart, indexEnd - indexStart);
```